# ASP.Net Dropdown List Doesn't Re-Display My Selected Option

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have a 4 page ASP.NET form which is storing data in the session. All this is working fine but I'm having a problem retreiving the value the user initial selected from my dropdown list.

**1st Page HTML With DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInnoc" runat="server" class="form-control">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">- - Please Select - -</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Male">Male</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="Female">Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**1st Page Code Behind Which Re-displays Selected Value**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtData1.Text == string.Empty && Session["pg1input"] != null)
        {
            txtData1.Text = Session["pg1input"].ToString();
        }

        if (ddlInnoc.SelectedValue == string.Empty && Session["pg1dd"] != null)
        {
            ddlInnoc.SelectedValue = Session["pg1dd"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void pg1button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["pg1input"] = txtData1.Text;
        Session["pg1dd"] = ddlInnoc.SelectedValue;
        Response.Redirect("/Session/pg2.aspx");
    }
```

**Page 3 HTML Code**

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Name:"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 form-control-static">
                        <%=Session["pg1input"] %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Sex:"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 form-control-static">
                        <%=Session["pg1dd"] %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-12">
          <asp:LinkButton ID="pg1EditButton" runat="server" OnClick="pg1EditButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default">
               <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
          </asp:LinkButton>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Page 3 Edit Button Code Behind**

```
protected void pg1EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Session/pg1.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue it added

```
if (ddlInnoc.SelectedValue != "0" && Session["pg1dd"] != null)
{
     ddlInnoc.SelectedValue = Session["pg1dd"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think condition `if (ddlInnoc.SelectedValue == string.Empty` is incorrect becuase initial value of ddlInnoc.SelectedValue will be 0 and not the String.Empty..try checking initial value as "0"

Comment: If I use value == "0" when i return to the page it displays as "Please Select" so i have updated it to != "0" and this then returns the selected value

Comment: Right, but main thing is that it will not be string.Empty in your case.